# DJI Windows sample code - USB connection - cannot view FPV

Tags: dji-sdk

Using VS 2019 and Windows SDK 0.3.1 I cloned and executed the SDK sample code correctly. Trying to connect to the smart controller of Mavic 2 doesn't work. 
FPV page says 'turn work mode green first'. I guess there is no outgoing serial communication from the sample code towards controller.
Connection with Assistant 2 Mavic does work normal. 
Device manager shows under Com and LPT: CDC Serial (Interface 1) COM4 and under USB devices: ADB interface. 
Component handler doesn't communicate either with the controller.

I am clearly missing something in setting up correctly the USB connection between the sample code and controller.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar issue recently Martin. I was trying to follow the DJI/Windows SDK tutorials and got the DJISdkManager to register but could not invoke the FPV on my Mavic 2 Pro.

I ended up following the guidelines [here](https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/documentation/connection/Mavic2.html)

Turns out I think I had the wrong version of DJI Assistant 2 installed (legacy from having a Mavic 1) I updated and used the Zadig program to install a WinUSB driver for the remote controller. After that, I got the FPV working handily enough.

This might help.

Edit: [Link](https://www.dji.com/ie/downloads/softwares/assistant-dji-2-for-mavic) to the correct version of the software I had to install.

Comment: I did install the correct DJI Assistant 2 (I have updated all firmware with it) and used all guidelines as suggested by you. Do you mean I have to change the current serial driver on Ports (com & lpt) to a WinUsb driver ? Could you pls. show a screenshot of the device manager ? Do you need to worry about the ADB and/or M500 drivers ?

Comment: I didn't do anything with ADB or M500 drivers.

Comment: I believe you have to use Zadig to ensure that the libusb-win32 Device listed uses a WinUSB driver and not whatever it is registered with by the OS (I'm not entirely sure on the specifics there) 

Finally, I added 2x extra capabilities to the .appxmanifest file's code behind. 

<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
and
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">

The tutorial only listed the serial port entry, but I've just added both as an extra precaution. I haven't tested it without the USB cap.

Comment: "Could you pls. show a screenshot of the device manager ?" 

I can't seem to post a screen shot, but my Device Manager has libusb-win32 listed for the RC when it is connected to the computer under the Universal Serial Bus devices tree node

Comment: I did use Zadig to set Win USB driver. I also monitored for outgoing packages (serial CDC interface) and see no outgoing packages at all from the sample code to the controller. I do see when the smart controller is connecting but no handshake, no communication. The tutorial seems to lack behind, in the latest github repo the .appxmanifest does include both the USB and Serial capabilities codes. I cannot find the reason why the sample code is not outputting any data via USB.

Comment: Sorry @Martin, I'm not sure I can help from here -- I'm still quite new to DJI's SDK. 

I agree that the tutorials are a bit lacking but hopefully someone from DJI can shed some light on your problem from here. 

Alternatively, have you tried contact them directly? 

If anything else comes to mind about hoops I had to jump through I can get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the reply from DJI dev.

Windows SDK is not compatible with the smart controller, only with regular controller.